# set-cookie on http://localhost won't set

Tags: django, cookies, session-cookies

I have a react (next.js) project with django+graphql backend.
Is it possible to set session cookie while having frontend hosted on `http://localhost:5000`?
I tried setting django variables for httpOnly and secure and I see cookie coming from backend, however it won't set no matter what.

Example of response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5000
Content-Length: 168
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 21 Mar 2023 15:29:38 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.16
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=myCsrfCookie; expires=Tue, 19 Mar 2024 15:29:38 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: sessionid=mySessionIdCookie; expires=Tue, 04 Apr 2023 15:29:38 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=None
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem was I didn't include `credentials: 'include'`